# syntax error with tkinter

Tags: python, syntax, tkinter

I am currently in the process of developping a small python game  and I am having an error. I can't make heads or tail of it so any help would be much appreciated.

Here's the part of the code that gives me trouble ( the "<" symbol is outlined in red" )

```
<\keyrelease>
<\keypress>
```

And here's the link to the full code with the ressources :
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/f18hhixhesy8rud/zfrjtoRJ-q

EDIT: This is the code from the Dropbox link:

```
fenetre.bind_all("<keypress>",enfoncee) 
fenetre.bind_all("<keyrelease>",relachee)
```

Comment: What do you expect those lines to do? They're not Python code, which is why you're getting your syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code sample must have gotten formatted incorrectly, here's what I saw in your Dropbox link:

```
fenetre.bind_all("<keypress>",enfoncee) 
fenetre.bind_all("<keyrelease>",relachee)
```

The Tkinter Event formats are specific and case-sensitive. You can read up on them here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm

Instead of `<keypress>` and `<keyrelease>`, you need `<Key>` and `<KeyRelease>`.

Comment: It works now but when I try to move my character it won't budge :

Comment: here's the link to my new version : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2b9jd6oyjf2gzkx/oFTsU7jXAC

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the slashes.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def key(event):
    print "pressed", repr(event.char) 

frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
frame.bind("<Key>", key)
frame.pack()
root.mainloop()
```